# How can use One media convert to give internet connection to 4 houses?

Tags: wireless-router, internet-connection, switch

Can I use one media converter to give internet access to 3 houses near my. My ISP saying he will be needing 2 media converts at each home with 8 port switch at each home. is it necessary? I mean can't we connect like

Fiber optic cable -> Media Converter -> 8 port switch -> (via LAN Cable) WiFi Routers ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, what your ISP is saying is "Don't share your internet connection, we want to sell you one each".

2 Media converters for fibre seems odd - the topology most fibre ISPs (in singapore) use is an ONT (which will take one fibre input, and will let you use one of its ports to connect to your gear) to a consumer router to everything else. Even if it was a simple converter, two media converters means two ethernet connections in, with a maximum of 2GBPS and the need for fancy things like bonding. Its strange.

I'd note, laying lan cable between *houses* is tricky. You'd want to have it somewhere where it won't get taken out by environmental hazards, wild backhoes, rabbits and so on. You'd want conduit and suitably rated cable in many cases. You'd need to crimp the cable and so on.

I'd doublecheck why he needs two, and see how pricing differs if its a single home that has it.

Comment: ya ISP is like will give connection to each house from 4 different cables, which is utter non sense, what I suggested is give one cable to apartment of 6 flats attach one media converter give its o/p to 8 port switch and then distribute via LAN from 8 port switch, because the apartment I was staying previously there my ISP gave connection to my flat from 8 port switch they were having 3 8 port switch in that apartment and gave connection from those switch to each flat, each flat has its own username and password given from ISP